# WMI Access is denied, find permissions problem

Tags: windows, permissions, wmi

I am trying to run process(console executable) on remote PC from asp.net application using WMI and get "Access is denied" problem. I have checked all event viewer logs on remote PC, no information related this. Where do I start searching for problem? Does Windows has some kind of permission monitor tool? 
Also I have tried to use Procmon.exe but hard to understand what to search, my process even do not listed in Procmon.

Regards,
Tomas

Answer (score 0):

It's worth taking a look here: http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2007/08/14/wmi-troubleshooting-permissions.aspx

Comment: It is now here: [Ask The Performance Team - WMI Troubleshooting: Permissions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/wmi-troubleshooting-permissions/ba-p/372496)